# Creating RSS Feed with PHP but I'm getting Encoding Error

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to create an RSS feed for my site, I've got 99% of it working, however I'm currently having a problem. When I go to input the description field it presents me with an encoding error. The description field in the database is text so I presumed it would work.

```
<?php
// Login to Databse
$link = mysqli_connect("DB_HOST", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS", "DB_NAME");
 
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            
            // RSS XML Header
            header( "Content-type: text/xml");
                echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
                echo "<rss version='2.0'>";
                    echo "<channel>";
                    echo "<link>https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "</link>";
                    echo "<language>en</language>";
        
            // RSS Add Content
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<item>";
                    echo "<title>" . $row['title'] . "</title>";
                    echo "<link>https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/" . $row['self'] . "-"  . $row['id'] .  "</link>";
                    echo "<description>" . $row['description'] . "</description>";
                    echo "<enclosure url='https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/public/upload/cover/" . $row['image'] .  "' length='174093' type='image/webp'/>";
                echo "</item>";
            }
    
            // End RSS Feed
            echo "</channel>";
        echo "</rss>";
        
        // End Feed
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

My data types are varchar's and int's, even if I change the text to varchar I get the same error:

```
error on line 1 at column 596: Encoding error
```

I'm hoping I'm just been stupid but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the description for anything contain any "fun" characters? Something other than alphanumeric and common punctuation?

Comment: I don't think anything in this is considered "fun" haha; "After being held captive in an Afghan cave, billionaire engineer Tony Stark creates a unique weaponized suit of armor to fight evil." Perhaps the "," ?

Comment: I sussed it, it's the quotation marks in another "description" any idea how I can encode or remove specific characters ?

Comment: Use something like [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument) to build the doc where the library handles encoding and structural concerns properly and transparently.